# How to query maximum marks?

Tags: mysql, sql

My database for a college:

```
Student       (StudentID, FName,LName, ....)  
StudentMarks  (StudentID,SubjectID, Marks)  
Subject       (SubjectID, CourseID, SubjectName)
```

How to query the SubjectID in which student, say ENG1000, scored maximum marks?

Comment: I think the spec is not clear. I interpreted it as, "For each subject, determine the maximum marks (100%) for a subject then determine whether student ENG1000 has achieved this in any subject they have taken." But there is no attribute in the schema to model the maximum marks for a given subject: perhaps they are all out of 100 (i.e. percentages), in which case the query is trivial. However, all of the answers so far have taken different interpretations, hence the conclusion that the spec is not clear.

Comment: You should define the term 'Maximum Marks'. Maximum of possible scores, maximum of all that students scores or maximum of ALL students scores?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SubjectID
FROM StudentMarks
WHERE Marks = (SELECT MAX(Marks) FROM StudentMarks);
```

Comment: I want a particular student who has scored maximum subject

Comment: The OP wants the ID of the subject in which the 'ENG1000' student has scored maximum marks. Your result doesn't filter by StudentID currently.

Comment: The result did not filter the studentID

Comment: The join should not only be on Marks, as there could be two or more students who have achieved the same marks in different subjects.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to give you the full solution, as that isn't the best way of learning :)

If you only need the SubjectID and already have the StudentID, then you can write a statement using only the StudentMarks table without having to join to either of the others. Think about which aggregate function(s) you can use and pay attention to:

- How you restrict/group the results by StudentID
- Retrieving the MAXimum score from that set

Once you've achieved this, have a think about how you could maybe retrieve the name of the student, too, plus the name of the subject in which they've scored so well - you'll have to think about joining to other tables for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    StudentID , SubjectID ,Marks
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY Marks DESC) AS score_rank
    INTO #temp
FROM StudentMarks

SELECT 
        StudentID, SubjectID, Marks
FROM    #temp 
WHERE   score_rank = 1

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: The OP wants the maximum score for a particular student, 'ENG1000'.

Comment: I guess he wants the SubjectId with high score??

Comment: So my answer should give you the right subject Id, have you tried it?

Comment: How DO I filter both student ID and Max Marks

Comment: @Yaqab Ahmad - The StudentMarks table contains *all* the scores, not just those from the 'ENG1000' student. If I'm understanding correctly, the result needs to be only for that one student, and should output the SubjectID of the one(s) in which they've achieved maximum marks.

Comment: MySQL has not implemented window functions.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to make a few assumptions: ENG1000 is a StudentID, and 'max' marks is 100...

```
SELECT SubjectID FROM StudentMarks
WHERE StudentMarks.StudentID = ENG1000
AND StudentMarks.Marks = 100
```

Comment: Yes ENG1000 is student ID and max marks is the maximum of the marks that student has scored in some subjects that I need to find through query

Comment: How DO I filter both student ID and Max Marks

Comment: @user976027 The example I gave does filter by StudentID and Marks, could you be more specific?

Comment: It is the Maximu marks not 100 it could be any between 1 and 100 that the student has scored in certain subject

Comment: A combination of mine and Devan's answers should give you everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT subjectID
FROM StudentMarks
WHERE studentID = 'ENG1000'
ORDER BY mark DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: What if the student has scored the same top mark in more than one subject?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will perform well

```
SELECT SubjectID
FROM StudentMarks
WHERE Marks = (SELECT MAX(Marks)
FROM StudentMarks) AND studentID = 'ENG1000' ;
```